# liferay hook deployment - event class not found exception

Tags: java, hook, liferay, jboss5.x, liferay-6

I create a hook plugin with **liferay-sdk-6.0.6** and define a `servlet.service.events.pre` event handler :

```
<service>
    <service-type>servlet.service.events.pre</service-type>
    <service-impl>com.ggd543.liferay.ServicePreAction</service-impl>
</service>
```

When i deploy it onto liferay-6.0.6-ce bundled jboss 5.1.0 GA, I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.startup.events
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(HookHotDeployListener.java:569)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(HookHotDeployListener.java:218)
    ... 68 more
```

Is there any wrong in my `liferay-hook.xml` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From Liferay 6 you dont define events like that in liferay-hook.xml. You have to create property hook and define your event in the property file. Some thing like below

**liferay-hook.xml**

```
<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>

</hook>
```

**portal.properties**

```
servlet.service.events.pre=com.ggd543.liferay.ServicePreAction
```

Comment: What about service , service-type, service-impl ?

Comment: they are still there, if you see the liferay-hook_6_0_0.dtd, you will see what all are still supported

Comment: where should i place the portal.properties ?  is it in my-hook/WEB-INF/portal-ext.properties?

Comment: WEB-INF/src/portal.properties  http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-Portal+Properties